# Creating nested menus in bash

Tags: bash

I want to create more menus under option "a" when selected. If the user entered option "a" I want it to have a couple menus for you to select and for one of the options is to return to the "Main Menu". This is the 2 problems I'm having trouble with. I tried doing this same format I have below for the menu here and put it under "A" block of code but that didn't work.

```
#!/bin/bash

ok=0;

while ((ok==0))
do
echo "Main Menu:"
echo -e "\t(a) More Menu Options "
echo -e "\t(b) Exit"
echo -n "Please enter your choice:"
read choice
case $choice in
    "a"|"A")
    ok=1

    ;;
    "b"|"B")
    exit
    ;;
        *)
        echo "invalid answer, please try again"
        ;;

esac
done
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why not put the same cycle inside?

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

while :
do
echo "Main Menu:"
echo -e "\t(a) More Menu Options "
echo -e "\t(b) Exit"
echo -n "Please enter your choice:"
read choice
case $choice in
    "a"|"A")
    while :
    do
    echo "Secondary menu"
    echo -e "\t(c) Print this menu again"
    echo -e "\t(d) Return to main menu"
    echo -n "Please enter your choice:"
    read choice1
    case $choice1 in
        "c"|"C")
        ;;
        "d"|"D")
        break
        ;;
            *)
            echo "invalid answer, please try again"
            ;;
    esac
    done
    ;;
    "b"|"B")
    exit
    ;;
        *)
        echo "invalid answer, please try again"
        ;;

esac
done
```

There is also `select` command which creates menus:

```bsh
select i in ant bee cat
do 
    echo $i
    break
done
```

Let's run it:

```bsh
$ select i in ant bee cat; do echo $i; break; done
1) ant
2) bee
3) cat
#? 2
bee
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
#!/bin/bash

submanual(){
while :
do
echo "sub Menu:"
echo -e "\t(x) Options 1"
echo -e "\t(y) Options 1"
echo -e "\t(e) Back"
echo -n "Please enter your choice:"
read c
case $c in
    "x"|"X")
    # Options 1 and its commands
    ;;
    "y"|"Y")
    # Options 2 and its commands
    ;;
    "e"|"E")
    break
    ;;
        *)
        echo "invalid answer, please try again"
        ;;
esac
done
}

while :
do
echo "Main Menu:"
echo -e "\t(a) More Menu Options "
echo -e "\t(b) Exit"
echo -n "Please enter your choice:"
read choice
case $choice in
    "a"|"A")
    submanual
    ;;
    "b"|"B")
    exit
    ;;
        *)
        echo "invalid answer, please try again"
        ;;

esac
done
```

Comment: Did you read my code carefully before you vote it down? Seems you are not shell guy at all.

Comment: really, not show the manual again? did you really test it? If not, do that, then answer me.

Comment: Man, How can I know what OP need put there to show more options. I have to leave the space for OP

Comment: fix the infinite loop issue, then OP should know how to handle the submanual.

Comment: Thank you for the edit. Now you are actually answering the question and your code works as expected. I will delete my comments (I suggest you do the same since they are no longer relevant) and have changed my downvote to an upvote.